# Google drive integration with swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm continuously getting error message "Daily limit for unauthenticated use exceed. Continued use requires signup." after successful login for the first time. I was able to get all my files from the account. but after that I am not able to get into account. What I'm missing? I have done code according to [google drive developers console](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ios?ver=swift)

1. AppDelegate.swift

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

       // Initialize google sign-in
       var configureError: NSError?
       GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
       assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(String(describing: configureError))")
       return true
   }

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

       return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                annotation: annotation)

   }

   @available(iOS 9.0, *)
   func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
       let sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String
       let annotation = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
       return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                            annotation: annotation)
   }
   ```
2. DocumentUploadVC.swift

   ```
   extension DocumentUploadVC : GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

   func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
         withError error: Error!) {
     if let error = error {
         self.showAlert("Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
         self.service.authorizer = nil
     } else {
         self.service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
         listFiles()
     }
   }

    func listFiles() {
       let gDriveList : GDriveFileListingVC = GDriveFileListingVC ()
       self.push(gDriveList)
     }
   }
   ```
3. GDriveFileListingVC.swift

   ```
   private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeDriveReadonly]

   private let service = GTLRDriveService()

   func showGoogleDriveData() {

   let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
   query.pageSize = 10
   service.executeQuery(query,
                        delegate: self,
                        didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:))
   )
   }

   // Process the response and display output
   @objc func displayResultWithTicket(ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
                                  finishedWithObject result : GTLRDrive_FileList,
                                  error : NSError?) {

   if let error = error {
       activityIndicatorBGView?.isHidden = true
       activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
       self.showAlert("Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
       return
   }

   var text = "";
   if let files = result.files, !files.isEmpty {
       text += "Files:\n"
       for file in files {
           text += "\(file.name!) (\(file.identifier!))\n"
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: That error means that your http request was missing an Authorization header containing an Access Token.

Comment: can you identify that in code? I'm not able to